# Forcing logins to happen over SSL in WordPress: Switching from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I'm using `define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);` in wp-config.php to force logins to happen over SSL. When I visit my login page the URL becomes HTTPS i.e. `https://example.com/wp-login`. The problem is when I then visit a different page such as the about me page, the page is still served via HTTPS i.e `https://example.com/about-me`

I expected the HTTPS to revert back to HTTP after I've left the login page but this didn't happen. Am I right to expect that should happen? If so, how can I ensure the HTTPS changes to HTTP when navigating away from the login page?

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL

Comment: When you log out the https still appears?

Comment: Yes. It appears until I either manually change the URL to HTTP or I perform a redirect to HTTP